# Why does the distance between the plates of a capacitor affect its capacitance?

Tags: capacitor, capacitance

Why does the capacitance of a capacitor increase when its plates are closer in distance to each other?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Intuitive approach: if the distance wouldn't be a factor then you would be able to place the plates at an infinite distance apart and still have the same capacitance. That doesn't make sense. You would expect a zero capacitance then.
If the capacitor is charged to a certain voltage the two plates hold charge carriers of opposite charge. Opposite charges attract each other, creating an electric field,

[image]

and the attraction is stronger the closer they are. If the distance becomes too large the charges don't feel each other's presence anymore; the electric field is too weak.

Comment: true, and nice graphic, but let's play devil's advocate: just because for a given charge Q, the electric field is stronger when the plates are closer doesn't give you any intuitive indication that the voltage is stronger or weaker (Q=CV so higher capacitance means lower voltage for fixed charge). I don't buy the infinite argument, either: infinitesimal electric fields integrated over an infinite distance gives an indeterminate voltage.

Comment: -1, because conductors at an infinite distance actually have *finite* capacitance. Consider a single conductor sphere w/ radius R1, and charge Q. Outside the sphere, the field is Q/(4*pi*eps0*r^2), and if you integrate this from radius R1 to infinity, you get voltage V = Q/(4*pi*eps0*R1). If you superpose the electric fields of another sphere with voltage -Q of radius R2 infinitely far away, you get a total voltage between the spheres of Q/(4*pi*eps0)*(1/R1+1/R2) -- it's additive rather than subtractive (opposite signs of Q cancel the opposite path integral), so C = Q/V = 4*pi*eps0/(1/R1+1/R2)

Comment: @Jason - parallel plate cap: \$C = \frac{\epsilon A}{d}\$. \$\epsilon\$ and A are finite, d is infinite, so C = 0. QED

Comment: Wrong. The equation only applies for d << the dimensions of the plate.

Comment: For parallel discs of radius R and distance d, a closer approximation is \$C = \epsilon [\pi R^2/d + R ln (16\pi R/d - 1)]\$, but even that is still an approximation -- see http://www.santarosa.edu/~yataiiya/UNDER_GRAD_RESEARCH/Fringe%20Field%20of%20Parallel%20Plate%20Capacitor.pdf

Comment: @Jason - I guess you're right (it's been a long time...), but your last formula isn't usable; the argument of the logarithm would be negative.

Comment: yeah, I know, I went to try to extend for d -> infinity, and came to the same conclusion. Can't find a useful formula yet, and it's bugging me. I'm asking on physics.stackexchange....

Comment: @st e test (why is it deleting the @ste part at the beginning of a comment if I delete the space?)

Comment: @Jason - explained [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/657/names-disappearing-in-comments-why)

Comment: Hmm. Apparently with plate separations that are not << the plate dimensions, this is a difficult problem and has no analytical answer (e.g. conquered only by numerical analysis, w/ no explicit equation that doesn't have derivatives or integrals or sums). See http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.167.3341&rep=rep1&type=pdf and http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i2/contents/IntegralEquations/IntegralEquations.pdf

Comment: the work needed to move a test charge on one of the plates decreases when the other plate is closer (far away the plates look like point charges and the field does depend on the distance) and hence the electric potential decreases so the capacitance increases

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I did not notice the small arrows. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 9):

FIG 1 to 4: Capacitor:

[image: Capacitor diagram]

It is obvious that as the distance between plates decreases, their ability to hold charges increases.

fig.1 = If there is unlimited distance between plates, even a single charge would repel further charges to enter the plate.

fig.2 = if distance bet plates decreases, they can hold more charges due to attraction from the opposite charged plate.

fig.4 = with minimum distance between the plates, the max attraction between them enables both to hold max amount of charges.

As Capacitance C = q/V, C varies with q if V remains the same (connected to a fixed potential elec source). So, with decreased distance q increases, and so C increases.

Remember, that for any parallel plate capacitor V is not affected by distance, because:
V = W/q (work done per unit charge in bringing it from on plate to the other)

and W = F x d

and F = q x E

so, V = F x d /q      = q x E x d/q

V = E x d
So, if d (distance) bet plates increases, E (electric field strength) would drecrese and
V would remain the same.

Comment: Of course $V$ is affected by distance. You have $V = E \times d$ in your final sentence for example. And $V$ is an integral of $E$ over some distance so as $d$ increases we are adding up more of $E$ so $V$ should increase.

Answer (score 7):

Capacitance is charge per EMF.  Specifically Farads are Coulombs per volt.  As you move the plates closer at the same applied voltage, the E field between them (Volts per meter) increases (Volts is the same, meters gets smaller).  This stronger E field can hold more charges on the plates.  Remember that the charges on the plates would otherwise repell each other.  It takes a E field to keep them there, and the stronger the E field the more charges it can keep there.  The higher charge at the same voltage means higher capacitance (more Coulombs at the same Volts).

Comment: almost answers it... there's kind of a handwaving thing here about stronger E field implying more charge, but I'll give you a +1: linearity arguments (Q should be proportional to E) are probably good enough.

Comment: @Jason, I was trying to keep it simple, because it actually is a pretty simple concept.  It's hard to judge what level of detail the OP wants, so I don't know where to stop explaining and start waving the hands.  Too far either way is bad.  If you don't believe that, take a look at the mess Matt's answer has turned into.  Without direction from the OP, I picked what I thought was a reasonable tradeoff he can ask more about if he wants to.

Answer (score 3):

To get technical, you want to look at [Coulomb's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law).  This states that

> "The magnitude of the Electrostatics force of interaction between two point charges is directly proportional to the scalar multiplication of the magnitudes of charges and inversely proportional to the square of the distances between them."
>   ***- Wikipedia***

The formula for this is:

> \$F = k_e \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}\$

Where \$F\$ is the electrostatic force between two charges, \$k_e\$ is a 'proportionality constant' (eg the dielelectric constant in a capacitor), and \$r\$ is the distance between the two charges \$q_1\$ and \$q_2\$.

There are other forms of the equation - such as this one specifically for an electric field:

> \$E = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\frac{q}{r^2}\$

Which tells us the force at a distance \$r\$ from the single point charge \$q\$.

If you want to start getting *really* technical then you need to start reading up on quantum mechanics and the interactions between particles and the energies involved in it.

When two particles (say electrons in this case) interact they send quantum particles between them (photons).  These, like the rats in the basement, require energy to move.  The greater the distance the higher the energy.  The higher the energy taken to move the photons the lower the charge left between the two plates.

That's a very simplistic view of it and there is one helluva lot more detail in there to be discovered - such things as Quantum Tunneling, Leptons, Fermions, Bosons, etc.   It's fascinating reading if you have the time.  I'd recommend Steven Hawking's *A Brief History of Time* as a good starting point.  Follow that up with F. David Peat's *Superstrings and the Search for the Theory of Everything* and you won't go far wrong.  While both these books are getting a bit long in the tooth now and the theories are all still evolving, they give good insights into the workings of the universe at a subatomic level.

Comment: You spell out the formulas which show the relationship to distance, but I got the impression OP already knows that. He doesn't ask *if* distance affects capacitance, but *why* it does. `if (nitpicking) then say_sorry;`

Comment: @stevenvh The why is what the formulas demonstrate - we're getting into quantum mechanics here.  Is there a difference between what and why, and even where and when?  Oh, and it should be `if(nitpicking) { say_sorry(); }` ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was a difficult guy in college. I often asked why and the professor would always point to formula, which left me frustrated, because I didn't find that satisfying. There had always to be an intuitive explanation :-). And my code is pseudo-code, so it compiles correctly! ;-)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it segfaults on my core - it must be an incompatibility in firmware.  For more into the "Why" you want to read "A Brief History of Time" (Steven Hawking) followed by "Superstrings and the search for the theory of everything" (F David Peat) and you'll have a lot more knowledge, but still be non the wiser ;)

Comment: @stevenvh - Your code compiles fine with Delphi & FreePascal :o}

Comment: @Mike - Yes, I know! but I thought if I'd mention Delphi we're in for a comments flood, and we're off topic already :-)

Comment: @Mike @stevenvh Shall we move this conversation to SO? ;)

Comment: @MattJenkins, forgive me if my understanding is poor. At a quantum level the photons are not sent back and forth between the particles but generated as energy is changed between the particles they often radiate or absorb photons. I may not know at a low enough level, but that is my understanding that it is the particle form of electromagnetic radiation while this is an electric dipole moment.

Comment: @kortuk It all depends on what theory you read.  The one I have here thinks that the energy is transferred by using the photons.  The photons are created by 'borrowing' energy from the quantum vacuum and it's paid back after the transfer.  Personally I think it's all hogwash and it's actually little tiny people throwing spitballs around

Comment: Wow, you guys really know how to make a simple thing complicated.

Comment: @Olin Yup.  We learned from the best ;)

Comment: @OlinLathrop, that was my first thought, then I saw someone I thought might be wrong on the internet. I think the important part in a capacitor is that there is a stronger attraction force the closer they are all the harder they can work to correct the difference.

Comment: -1, because you do not mention any equations involving capacitance.

Answer (score 0):

When the plates are far apart the potential difference is maximum (because between the plates you travel through a larger distance of the field, and the field also isn't cancelled out by the field of the other plate), therefore the capacitance is less. As the plates move closer, the fields of the plates start to coincide and cancel out, and you also travel through a shorter distance of the field, meaning the potential difference is less, therefore capacitance increases C=Q/V, because the charge on the plates is fixed, you are just moving the plates. When there is a dielectric, the electric field decreases i.e. is cancelled by the dielectric, therefore V decreases between the plates (a line integral of this lesser field), therefore capacitance increases.

For the same charge, less potential is required, because the close proximity of the plates allow the potential to be partially cancelled, and therefore this ratio is called capacitance, because for the same potential you can achieve more charge on the plates.

Answer (score -2):

A key thing to understand is that if a plate has more electrons coming in than going out, it's going to build up a negative charge which will serve to repel any more electrons from coming in (likewise for a plate with more electrons leaving than arriving).  It wouldn't take very many electrons coming into an isolated plate for the charge to build up to millions of volts.  If, however, there is a positively-charged plate near the negatively-charged one, the positively-charged plate would try to pull electrons toward itself and consequently toward the negative plate (likewise the negatively-charged plate would try to push electrons away from itself and consequently away from the positive plate).  The force from the positive plate trying to draw in electrons cannot completely counter-balance the force of the negative plate trying to push them away, but it if the plates are close together it can counterbalance it significantly.  Unfortunately, if the plates are too close, the plates won't be able to build up too much of a charge before electrons start hopping from one plate to the other.

It turns out there's trick to ease this problem.  Some materials allow electrons to move about within them, but they don't allow electrons to enter or leave.  Placing such a material (called a dielectric) between the two plates can greatly improve the performance of a capacitor.  What happens, essentially, is that the charge difference between the negative and positive plates moves the electrons in the dielectric toward the positive one.  The side of the electric toward the negative plate thus has a relative shortage of electrons, drawing electrons toward the negative plate, while the side toward the positive plate has a surplus of electrons, pushing electrons away from the positive plate.  This behavior can improve the performance of a capacitor by many orders of magnitude.

Comment: -1: you're talking about dielectric strength, but you don't make any mention, either quantitatively or qualitatively, about the capacitor's capacitance.

Comment: @Jason S: Capacitance is the ratio of the amount of charge imbalance to the amount of electromagnetic force required to hold that level of charge imbalance.  Perhaps I should have defined capacitance in terms of coulombs per volt, but I believe the first paragraph pretty well answers the question that was asked.  The second question was intended to make clear that it's not just the electrons on the plates that play a role in capacitor behavior; those in the dielectric are often very important as well.

Comment: @supercat: It's not electromagnetic force.  Magnetism has nothing to do with capacitors.  It's stricly about EMF (ElectroMotive Force).  This is the physical property often measured in Volts.

Comment: @Orin Lathrop: Sorry, my terminology in the comment was wrong, though I don't use the term "electromagnetic force" in the answer.  I think the key point I was trying to put forth in my answer was that electrons can flow into the negative plate, despite the charge imbalance, because they are attracted toward the positive plate.  Without the attraction from the positive plate, one could push a few electrons into the negative plate, but not a whole lot.

Comment: @supercat: I still see nothing in your answer or comments to explain why capacitance increases when the plates are closer. Why doesn't capacitance decrease when the plates are closer? Why doesn't it stay the same? The quantitative/qualitative behavior of *capacitance* as a function of plate distance is different from (but related to) the quantitative/qualitative behavior of *charge* or of *electric field*.

Comment: ...and "It wouldn't take very many electrons coming into an isolated plate for the charge to build up to millions of volts": misleading. Voltage is measured between two points (by a line integral of the E field between those points), and without defining both those points, it's meaningless. If you put Q coulombs of charge on a conducting sphere of radius R, the voltage between the sphere surface and a particular point in space is well-defined. Depending on the point location, it could be 1V, or 10V, or 3261.8V, or 10^6V.

Comment: @Jason S: Certainly, capacitance relates to the relative charge imbalance (number of electrons) between the positive and negative electrode that can be created with a given amount of elecromotive force, and so in some sense one cannot define the capacitance or voltage of a single electrode.  On the other hand, I think it's easiest to start by focusing on one electrode (negative one in this case) and recognize that the other one will have equal and opposite behavior.  Perhaps I need to explicitly state that?

Comment: @Jason S: While it's true that voltage is generally a relative rather than absolute quantity, absolute voltage is defined relative to a neutrally-charged object an infinite distance away.  In my explanation, I was striving for brevity rather than absolute analytical precision.  The basic concept is that a plate with an excess of electrons will try to push away more electrons unless something else helps draw more electrons to the plate.  A positively-charged plate nearby will have such an effect.  The closer the positively-charged plate, the greater the effect.

Comment: @supercat: "A positively-charged plate nearby will have such an effect. The closer the positively-charged plate, the greater the effect" -- true, but what does that have to do with capacitance? Physical force and voltage (electromotive force) are vaguely related but are not the same thing.

Comment: "so in some sense one cannot define the capacitance or voltage of a single electrode." -- with one electrode, it's not capacitance, but it is called self-capacitance.

Comment: @Jason S: I wasn't talking about physical force.  Electrons want to get as close to the positively-charged electrode as they can, and are even somewhat willing to flow into the negatively-charged electrode to do so (though as more electrons do this, the repulsion from the increasing negative charge of the negative electrode will counteract the attraction of the positive electrode).  As for capacitance versus self-capacitance, the same principle applies as for voltage, right?  Regarding capacitance as relative to a neutrally-charged point infinitely far away?

Comment: @supercat: re: electrons want to get close/repulsion/attraction: hmmm... I think we're just coming from different points of view. Regarding self-capacitance I think we're in agreement.

Comment: @Jason S: It is perhaps a somewhat different point of view, but I believe it is easier to understand conceptually than the more mathematically-rigorous approaches, and while it's not precise in its details it is close enough to be useful.  I tend to believe that an explanation of something which is 98% accurate but can be clearly understood, is often more useful than an explanation that is 100% accurate but incomprehensible.

Comment: @supercat: it's way too handwavy for me to upvote, sorry. I can go for nonrigorous explanations but not as it's presently stated. By the way I hope I'm not sounding overly negative; if you can add anything that would provide useful qualitative information, I'll upvote.